# Date format in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

How to cast date for the following format in SQL Server 2008 R2:

Date:

```
'29-01-2008 AM 12:00:00'
```

I have above date to check with the present date of the table.

How can I check only date from the above format?

Comment: I would strongly recommend you store datetime information as a date or datetime datatype instead of as strings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want only the date, then do:

```
 select convert(date, left('29-01-2008 AM 12:00:00', 10), 105)
```

This will convert it to a date and you can then compare it to `cast(getdate() as date).

The full list of formats for `convert()` is in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).