# Error converting data type varchar to date in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the date to check as shown below:

Input Date:

```
 17-09-2014
```

For which I am converting in my dynamic script:

Attempt #1:

```
 CAST((convert(date,@FDate, 105)) AS nvarchar(50))
```

Error:

> Error converting data type varchar to date.

Attempt #2:

```
 convert(date, @FDate, 105)
```

Error:

> The data types nvarchar and date are incompatible in the add operator.

Attempt #3:

```
 cast(@FDate as varchar(50))
```

Error:

> Error converting data type varchar to date.

One whole attempt, taken from the sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/38976 of the comments:

```
DECLARE @querys NVARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @Date DATE
SET @Date = '17-09-2014'

SET @querys = 'SELECT' + CAST((convert(date,@Date, 105)) AS nvarchar(50)) + ''
EXEC(@querys)
```

Comment: The error in 2 is showing that you are trying to concat a varchar with the converted date, convert(date,@FDate,105) is the way to go, the error for 1/2 seems to be in a non shown part of code
take a look at your question [Date format in SQL Server 2008 R2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25869271/date-format-in-sql-server-2008-r2)

Comment: @bummi, Please check sql fiddle-> Try 1: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/38976, Try 2: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/38978, Try 3: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/38974,

Comment: It'sshowing that your question is missleading,it alread has an error here `SET @Date = '17-09-2014'` with the definition `DECLARE @Date DATE` while 1 and 2 would lead to the assumption you are asking for FDate as varchar. Would be a close reason for "must include code to reproduce...."

Comment: Use `SELECT CONVERT(DATE, @input, 103)` - works for me

Comment: @marc_s, Yes! It does. But in dynamic sql script?

Comment: try to put DATEFORMAT DMY;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
convert(Datetime, @FDate,105)
```

I tried following script and it worked well for SQL Server 2005 and SQL Server 2012:

```
Declare @FDate varchar(100);
set @FDate='17-09-2014';
Select convert(Varchar(50), convert(Datetime, @FDate,105) ,105)
```

Verified your fiddle script, just had small change and it worked as expected.

Here is new script that I tested on fiddle:

```
DECLARE @qs VARCHAR(max)
Declare @FsDate varchar(100)
set @FsDate = '17-09-2014'

SET @qs = 'Select  convert(Varchar(50), convert(Datetime, '''+@FsDate+''',105) ,105) '

EXEC(@qs)
```

Comment: This helped me `convert(Datetime, '''+@FsDate+''',105)`. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this!

```
declare @a varchar(50)
set @a='17-09-2014'


select cast( right(@a,4)+'-'+SUBSTRING(@a,4,2)+'-'+LEFT(@a,2) as date)
```

### [FIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/21653)

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some confusion with [Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/us-en/library/ms187928.aspx).
Comparing your fiddels from the comments and your shown Attempts. Your fiddels are showing `DECLARE @Date DATE`;
The first argument is the targettype 
(Attempt #1) since your @FDate is already of type DATE `convert(date,@FDate, 105)`  will lead to a conversion from  DATE to DATE, your outer cast to nvarchar does not seem to work due to your locales.
(Attempt #2) is shown incomplete since the shown part `convert(date, @FDate, 105)` does work, even it won't change anything (conversion from  DATE to DATE)
(Attempt #3) does not seem to work due to your locales.

Your shown fiddle:

```
DECLARE @querys NVARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @Date DATE
SET @Date = '17-09-2014'
SET @querys = 'SELECT' + CAST((convert(date,@Date, 105)) AS nvarchar(50)) + ''
EXEC(@querys)
```

already is failing here `SET @Date = '17-09-2014'`, a save way independed from locales would be to use the format YYYYMMDD `SET @Date = '20140917'`.
Since you are trying to buid a varchar your targettype for CONVERT would by VARCHAR not DATE and you wuold have to add quotation marks, a simple PRINT @querys or SELECT @querys would show what you are trying to execute.

Taken from your fiddle, you are trying to convert a Date to a varchar and then add it to a dynamic SQL which you want to execute, so one way to go would be:

```
DECLARE @querys NVARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @Date DATE

SET @Date = '20140917'
-- get it as varchar
--SET @querys = ' SELECT ''' + convert(varchar(20),@Date,105) + ''''

--get it as date
SET @querys = ' SELECT convert(date,''' + convert(varchar(20),@Date,105) + ''',105)'

EXEC(@querys)
```

Comment: What if the date is  `@Date = '17092014'`?

Comment: A Date is a variable containing legal dates, how to fill it from varchars is depending on your locals or on the used convert function, the shown above is just filling it with the wished date in a way which will work always. What you are asking would read as 14.20.1709